# How to wait until one of several threads finishes?

Tags: java, multithreading

How to hang execution until one out of several other threads finishes? In other words I'd like to proceed only when one of anything is done. Thanks!

Comment: Where's your code? What have you done so far?

Comment: Sounds like you need the threads you are waiting on to initiate execution of the next step once they are done. Alternatively you could use a `wait/notify` style and have the main thread `wait`, one of the subthreads `notify`'s once it's done

Comment: [`ExecutorService.invokeAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-). Did you bother to do _any_ searching?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't think they wan't the other tasks to cancel, just do something once one finishes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @NeilLocketz did _you_ bother to read the documentation?

Comment: @BoristheSpider "Upon normal or exceptional return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled". I don't think thats the desired behavior

Comment: @Neil, thanks a lot! It is exactly what I need. It will be great if you can give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

if you use threadpool you can use Future.get().
when submit a task(Runnable or Callable),it returns a Future instance, you can use get() to wait for the task finish.

1. Future submit(Callable task);//return the call() result
2. Future submit(Runnable task, T result);//return specified result
3. Future submit(Runnable task);//return null

e.g. you can run the example below to know how it work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3);
    threadPool.submit(new Task(1,1000,semaphore));
    threadPool.submit(new Task(2,1000,semaphore));
    threadPool.submit(new Task(3,2000,semaphore));
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
        System.out.println("1 task has finished");
    }catch (InterruptedException e){

    }

}

public static class Task implements Runnable {
    Integer index;
    Integer sleep;
    Semaphore semaphore;

    public Task(Integer index, Integer sleep, Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.index = index;
        this.sleep = sleep;
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.printf("task %d begin\n", index);
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(sleep);
            System.out.printf("task %d end\n", index);
            semaphore.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            semaphore.release();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @WQLin thanks. In your example we seem to decide in advance which task will finish first. This is not what the question was.

Comment: @vkamenen oh, just one. I have modified code with Semaphore, but you must set how many tasks first, can it be OK?